# Creating new data frame by filtering by specific string results

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have “Data” DataFrame: with columns: 'CountryName', 'CountryCode', IndicatorName', 'IndicatorCode', 'Year', 'Value' from which I wish to extract data for literacy rate and money spent on education to check if it corelates. I wish to compare it between three countries: Norway (the highest human development index -HDI), Guyana (medium HDI) Central African Republic (the lowest HDI) as well as average for the world.

My plan was first to extract rows for both indicators and create new data frames:
`money=data.loc[data['IndicatorName']== 'Adult literacy rate, population 15+ years, both sexes (%)']'
'literacy=data.loc[data['IndicatorName']== 'Adult literacy rate, population 15+ years, both sexes (%)']`

Then do the same for the countries, marge countries DataFrames by IndicatorName and compare them side by side.

But when I type:
`Norway_money=money.loc[money['CountryName']== 'Norway']
                Norway_money.head`  I get:

"bound method NDFrame.head of Empty DataFrame Columns: [CountryName, IndicatorCode, Year, Value] Index: []"

And when I try: `Norway_money=money['CountryName'].str.contains ('Norway')`

I get Boolean data type instead of numeric values.

I am working on this data set for over a week now, and doing poor job. I find learning how to program really hard. I have searched through the forums, but I wasn’t able to find the answer which I would understand. Can anyone please help me and point me in the right direction?

Data set I am working on is located under the link https://www.kaggle.com/worldbank/world-development-indicators

I don't know how else I can add it.

Comment: No data no use. Add sample data and expected output. I dont think you have only one problem.

Comment: @Bharath I have edidted my question and added link to the data set

Answer (score 0):

> And when I try: `Norway_money = money['CountryName'].str.contains('Norway')`
>
> I get Boolean data type instead of numeric values

That's because you should select the indexes for which `money['CountryName'].str.contains('Norway')` returns `True` from the original dataframe.

This is done by `new_df = money[money['CountryName'].str.contains ('Norway')]`

Comment: Thank you for quick reply @ DeepSpace, I have replaced Norway_money = money['CountryName'].str.contains('Norway') with 
new_df = money[money['CountryName'].str.contains ('Norway')] and I still get Empty DataFrame

Comment: @Moonlit Obviously you will need to provide your actual data

Comment: @ DeepSpace I have added a link to my dataset, it has 5656458 rows

Answer (score 0):

I have found crude resolution to my problem. After filtering data to find desired indicator: 
`money=data.loc[data['IndicatorName']=='Expenditure on education as % of total government expenditure (%)']`,

I have saved results to csv file:
`money.to_csv('money_out')` and and reopened it again: `data_money=pd.read_csv('C://Week-6/money_out.csv')`.

Next step of filtering the countries does work now and I don’t get empty DataFrame anymore.